# When is a justifying theorem necessary?

Tags: set-theory

The title of this question may be a bit misleading, but I have more of a series of questions. In the book, Axiomatic Set Theory by Patrick Suppes, he talks of justifying theorems for definitions. One such example is when justifying the uniqueness of the union of two sets. He later goes on to say that definition by abstraction using set-builder notation needs no justifying theorem.

My questions are:

1.) When is this justifying theorem necessary?

2.) Is there a general idea that is being justified that is shared between most of these definitions?

3.) Why is the set-builder definition of a set an exception to this?

4.) Do these theorems come from the axioms?

5.) If there is one, can someone provide a justifying theorem for addition?

I may have greatly misunderstood something, and if someone could point that out if it is the case, I would also be grateful.

Comment: I assume the answer to 3 is that the theorem would be trivial, by extensionality. But the answer is that you always need such a theorem. If you define a specific object, you better have an argument showing its uniqueness. Of course if what you are doing is defining a class of objects, you are not claiming there is a unique object in the class (or even that the class is nonempty).

Comment: So would a justifying theorem for addition just be a proof by contradiction by assuming there is more than one p such that $m+n=p$?

Comment: Yes, or that there is no $p$ such that $m+n=p$.

Comment: When Suppes defines a new "object" in set theory, like e.g. the *domain* $\text {Dom}(A)$ of a *relation* $A$, he "justify" the definition proving that the defined set exists, i.e. Suppes proves that, for every relation $A$, the set $\text {Dom}(A)$ exists (and it is unique).